# Kivy - Removing widget by id

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy, kivy-language

I have the following code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout


class GUI(FloatLayout):
    def remove(self):
        self.remove_widget(self.ids.test)


class GUIApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return GUI()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    GUIApp().run()
```

And the corresponding `kv` file:

```
#:kivy 1.9.1

<GUI>:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            id: test
            text: 'Test'
            on_press: root.remove()
```

The button should be removed when clicked. However, this does not happen. If I remove the `BoxLayout` in the kv file, the program works as expected, and the button is removed. Why does this happen, and how can I remove a widget declared in a kv file? (I know I can replace the Button's `on_press` with `self.parent.remove_widget(self)`, but I have code in `root.remove()` besides removing the widget.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calling `remove_widget` of `GUI` object when your button's parent is actually `BoxLayout` inside it. `remove_widget` only deletes a direct children, not any descendant.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string('''
<GUI>:
    BoxLayout:
        id: layout
        Button:
            id: test
            text: 'Test'
            on_press: root.remove()
''')


class GUI(FloatLayout):
    def remove(self):
        self.ids.layout.remove_widget(self.ids.test)


class GUIApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return GUI()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    GUIApp().run()
```