# I have a question how removes widget with ids kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

Do not know how to remove widget With ids, example remove a label using ids with the remove widget

Ignore is part and only to be able to emviaIgnore is part and only to be able to send

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42173477/kivy-removing-widget-by-id

Comment: This question asked previously in stackoverflow and well answered

Comment: If you can get a reference to the widget using the `id`, then you can just to `some_widget.parent.remove_widget(some_widget)`. Where `some_widget` is the widget that you want to remove.